# Asking for a System Generator tag.

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

Does anyone create a tag for the xilinx program called 'System Generator'?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we ever get a ton of Xilinx questions that would be a good tag, but until then it's going to be overly narrow.

Comment: And if we do, the tag should be [Xilinx-System-Generator], not [System-Generator], right?